# how to retrieve region and province from gps android

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location

I'm new to android programming and I'm wondering if it's possible and how to retrive from the current position (I don't even know how to retrieve it) the region and the province.

Could you please post some code or tell me where I can find it?

Thanks!!!!!!

Matteo

Comment: One way is using google maps api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GPS TRACKING IN ANDROID PHONE:**

You can retrieve current location of the mobile phone using Android Location Manager.
Tutorial Reference: [GPS Tracking](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

**REVERSE GEOCODING WITH AVAILABLE LAT LONG:**

For getting the region and province, after getting current lat/long from phone, you can use the google reverse geocoding API that can be consumed via web-service.

The Google Reverse Geo-coding API is : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?`
Usage would be a GET REQUEST like : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452`
(You won't get a response if you just copy and paste the URL in browser)

(API Key is also not required for limited usage)

Reference : [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

Answer (score 1):

First, [find the location of your user using the Location Manager.](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
[Then, pass the location to Google's Geocoder for the address](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) (it contains the state, province and more)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the methode of Geocode class's (android.location) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html